# Outlook API - Anyone else unable to register native application?

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi

I am creating an app which will integrate with Outlook. The app consists of a back-end which will periodically sync calendar data with another system. To do this I want to use the REST api.

Based on instructions found here I believe I should use the [client authorization flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds) to authenticate.

Next I go to the registration portal [here](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) to register my app. As platform I add a 'Native Application'. Next I must enter a custom redirect URI. This is where things go wrong.

I try to enter http://localhost:8080/register for local testing. I get the following error:

`Your URI must be in the format of {scheme}://{domain}/{path}, and be limited to 255 characters in length.`

Basically any valid URI is denied. Interestingly if I try test://localhost:8080/register it is accepted.

Am I misunderstanding something? Is this a bug on Microsoft's page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `client_credentials` there isn't a callback URI. You're passing the client secret as your credentials and you don't need a Web or Native application defined.